# Cucumber DataTable Parsing Using Gherkin and Node JS

Tags: node.js, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to pass a few values as data table to a step in my feature file like below:

```
 When I provide guest information
  |firstName|secondName|
  |NameFirst|NameLast|
```

Now my stepdefinition.JS file has the steps definition function as below:

```
When(/^I provide guest information/, (guestInfoTable) =>{
      guestInfoTable.dataTable();
});
```

When running the code, I am getting the below error:
    guestInfoTable.dataTable is not a function

Can any one please tell me why I am not getting to read the data table in step definition?

Comment: Can any one please help me with it?

Comment: You are probably going wrong the way you are creating a hash? Datatables are stored in the form of hash in cucumber and hence, you would need to create a key, value pair function for the same.